# Setting up Github Highlighter in a Angular Page

Tags: git, angular, github, gist

I am trying to set this gist as highlighter in my Angular page.
I was following this tutorial

http://robertgreiner.com/2012/04/using-github-as-a-syntax-highlighter/

But is just dosent seem to load to load it up in the template as with normal server side applications.

Do i need to put this to angular cli.json file ?

Sample gist -

`<script src="https://gist.github.com/jhades/9c439200c392d4e32c5b28c1c8052d02.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gist` doesn't work directly with angular app like the way suggested in blog. In order to have `gist` working properly with angular app you need to embed your script & html code inside an iframe. You can try using [ngx-gist](https://github.com/jasonhodges/ngx-gist) (take look on [component file](https://github.com/jasonhodges/ngx-gist/blob/master/lib/ngx-gist.ts)) which you might can find useful. You can find npm package details [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-gist).